# XSLT: convert a double to a date in xsl

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I wanna use the function:
days-from-duration($newDate - $oldDate)
to calculate the difference between my date and current-date() ($newDate).

My problem is that this function will not take my date, which is of the type double.
It has the format: dd.mm.yyyy ($oldDate)

My question is how do i convert a double with this format to a date so i can use this function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. How can a double be in the format dd.mm.yyyy?

Comment: When i get it from my XML it has this format 30.10.2016, and looks like a date, but when i try to use it with current-date() it says the datatypes do not match.

Comment: I get it from a xml using xsl:value-of.

Answer (score 0):

A value of `30.10.2016` cannot be a *double*. If that's what your input contains, treat it as a *string* and extract the individual components to assemble a valid date formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<input>30.10.2016</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="my:reformat-date">
    <xsl:param name="datestring"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring($datestring, 7, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring($datestring, 4, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring($datestring, 1, 2)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="xs:date(concat($y, '-', $m, '-', $d))" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <difference>
        <xsl:value-of select="days-from-duration(current-date() - my:reformat-date(input))"/>
    </difference>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (when applied today, Nov 22, 2016)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<difference>23</difference>
```

---

Note that this assumes the input is formatted as `DD.MM.YYYY` - i.e. with leading zeros for single-digit days and months.

Comment: That looks really good. A question i have is: I have a xsl page where i wanna use this xsl:stylesheet? How do call this function on a xsl page?

Comment: @Chrizzy You call as shown in my example. I cannot be more specific than that, because I don't see your stylesheet. If you cannot make it work, edit your question and show a [mcve].